# Ubuntu 14.04 terminal up/down arrow special char issue

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, gnome-terminal

Today when I opened terminal and typed <kbd>↑</kbd> (up) / <kbd>↓</kbd> (down) arrow key to get the previous run commands, to my horror I am getting special characters all over the terminal screen.

Even when I typed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and typed tried accessing the history commands, I am getting the special chars only.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: do you get 'h' when press up arrow keys on any application? I am getting the same. I even tried this : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-fix-vim-up-down-keys-inserting-a-b-c-d-character-on-remote-ssh-session/ , still no solution :(

Comment: Are you using Dell Studio ? I am using Dell studio & getting the same problem. I also tried cyberciti.biz but no help :(

Comment: One more thing to notice in my case is only the first arrow up key is the one that prints h the subsequent arrow keys when fast pressed do not show any char. But if I press that key slowly each arrow up key press prints h. Are you seeing the same behaviour? Has the keypad gone bad? but that's probably not the case as I Virtual box windows OS there is no issue which boils down to having problems with Ubuntu.

Comment: Finally When I saw the settings of my keyboard again I noticed that, whenever I press the up key 'h' was also being pressed :(

Then I tried using the up key with ctrl key. This was the eureka moment for me. The h problem got solved.

I am not sure this is the right solution or not. I am trying to automate this & shall update this post whenever I succeed.